# How can i use a string which is having single quote (') as parameter i want to use a select query in C# like below

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

String ContractListst=" 'one','two','**Three's**','four' ";

String query = "select V_name,I_ID from tbl_Contract where V_name in (@ContractList)";

cmd.AddWithValue("@ContractList", ContractListst);

I want **Three's** to be considered as one string ignoring the single quote

Note:ContractList im getting from another function

Comment: You need to build and escape the in clause manually (by replacing `'` with `''` (2x`'`) and interpolate it into the SQL string as an IN clause cannot be parametrized (or use the form `IN (@p1, @p2, @p3)`).

Comment: You're going to have to use dynamic sql to get that in clause to have variables.

Answer (score 2):

Two things...

First, while you're not having a quoting issue in C#, as you're discovering there is a quoting issue in the resulting SQL.  So you have to escape the quote.  In SQL that's done by having two single-quotes in a row:

```
String ContractListst = "'one','two','Three''s','four'";
```

Second, while I applaud your use of query parameters (so many people don't use them at all), that's not going to work in this case.  They work great with individual values, but that `IN` clause is an entire clause and not just a single value.  So you're going to have to manually build it in this case:

```
String query = "select V_name,I_ID from tbl_Contract where V_name in (" + ContractListst + ")";
```

(or use `string.Format()`, or use a `StringBuilder`, there are multiple ways to do it and I just used the most direct one here for brevity)

Of course, if you ever do this with user input for an `IN` clause, *be very careful*.  (I'm quite certain there exist Stack Overflow questions already which discuss how to properly handle user input in a clause which can't be parameterized.)

Comment: I cant put two single-quotes  as my String is generated by a function is there any other way i can do this

Comment: @NiranjanMD: You're going to have to modify that function to generate valid SQL code then.  It's not a question of how to do this in C#, it's simply a question of creating valid SQL code to send to the SQL server.  However you decide to organize your code, the resulting string needs to be valid SQL.

Comment: Thank you David ,this is how im generating my String  string ContractListst = "'" + ContractList.Aggregate((x, y) => x + "','" + y) + "'"; where ContractList is a list which contain the string . Can you suggest me a right way to generate the String that can be passed to Sql Server

Comment: @NiranjanMD: You might try looping over the list instead of using `Aggregate()` and within that loop apply some sanitization of the string.  In this specific case, a `string.Replace()` from single-quotes to double-quotes would work.  But you may want to look through ADO.NET and see if there's a built-in function which can return an escaped-string.

Comment: @NiranjanMD I am going through same issue. have you got any solution for this